# How can I turn a Unity game into an MRAID-compliant playable ad?

Tags: unity, html5, advertisements

I need to create a mini-game, one really simple scene, and export it as a playable that comply with the [MRAID](https://www.aniview.com/academy/glossary/mraid/#:%7E:text=The%20Mobile%20Rich%20Media%20Ad,operating%20systems%20and%20app%20environments.) requirements.

Basically, I can export a WebGL.
The question is which adaptations the code needs to have (if any) in order to become compatible with MRAID.

I saw the [Luna](https://lunalabs.io/) tool that claims to solve this issue and export the scene on its own engine, to avoid any future adaptations, but honestly, I don't really understand what they're doing differently, if their engine still converts to JS and HTML5.

It seems really blurry at the moment and I can't find concrete, coherent answers.

All I'm getting from the company that approached my to get it done is "it needs to be MRAID compatible".

Does anyone have any experience and can shed some light on this subject?

Thanks in advance,
Omer

Comment: [As explained in the comments here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/187362/39518), this is not a task that's normally accomplished by exporting or converting a Unity game. Playable ads are normally built as completely separate entities with no relationship whatsoever to the game they are advertising. The Luna tool appears to be an editor for making a completely unrelated HTML5 ad that is *not* running your Unity game. It's just using the Unity Editor as an interface to make it easy to re-use assets like sprites and animations. If that's useful to you, then I'd recommend licensing that tool

Comment: Thank you! Well, it is important to mention, I am not advertising a game via the playable ad. I am making a small mini game from scratch, which suppose to act as a kind of commercial for a brand. In this case, considering the fact I'm familiar with the unity engine, you will advise me to build the mini game in Unity and then just export it with a tool like Luna?

Comment: Personally, I would not advise using Unity as a platform for making playable ads, no. It's not designed for that purpose, so it's likely you'll find a lot of Unity features you're used to using will not translate to an ad form as you desire. That could lead to a lot of nasty surprises at bad times during development. I think you will have a better time using a tool built for this purpose specifically, that is up-front about what it supports/does efficiently, and what it does not.

Comment: Looking at [the MRAID 3.0 specificaiton](https://iabtechlab.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/MRAID_3.0_FINAL_June_2018.pdf), it's a lot more than just exporting your game to HTML5. It mandates that your game must implement a number of javascript functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot turn a conventional* Unity game into an MRAID-compliant playable ad by just tweaking some code.

At least, not one with a download size and startup time that you would likely consider acceptable. The standard Unity engine is made for full-fledged apps, with a lot of flexibility and rich feature support that make it too heavyweight for mobile ads.

(* [You *may* be able to accomplish this with Unity's Project Tiny - it's one of the project's goals, but I don't have first-hand experience as to how well it's currently been achieved](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1A8hen2hLFY5FLkC5gd3JP2Z-IpHfnAX-CpYLK3aOdwA/edit#heading=h.rpixpnqdxqws))

What the Luna tool you've found does is to take your Unity content and export it as something that is *not* a Unity game and not running on the Unity engine, but on their own lighter-weight "Luna Engine" [which has different feature support](https://docs.lunalabs.io/docs/playable/getting-started/limitations). They're effectively piggybacking off of the Unity editor and the familiar workflows it offers, but then bypassing the normal Unity build process and runtime entirely with their own substitute.

If that's sufficient for your needs, then licensing that tool could be a way to solve your problem. Or if you're building this project from scratch, you may want to look into other MRAID-compatible ad creation tools. You may find some that are leaner, if they don't need to go out of their way to emulate Unity features in not-Unity.